# Spark RDD write to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a below Cassandra Table schema.

```
ColumnA Primary Key
ColumnB Clustering Key
ColumnC
ColumnD
```

Now, I have a Spark RDD with columns ordered as 
RDD[ColumnC, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnD]

So, when I am writing to the Cassandra Table, I need to make sure the ordering is correct. So, I am having specify the column ordering using SomeColumns

```
rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspace,table,SomeColumns("ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC","ColumnD))
```

Is there any way I Can pass all the column names as a list instead? I am asking that Cause I have around 140 Columns in my target table and cannot give all the names as part of SomeColumns. So, looking for a more cleaner approach.

PS: I cannot write it from a DataFrame, I Am looking only for solution based on RDD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following syntax to explode sequence into list of arguments:

```
SomeColumns(names_as_sequence: _*)
```

Update:

If you have a sequence of column names as strings, then you need to do:

```
SomeColumns(names_as_string_seq.map(x => x.as(x)): _*)
```

Comment: It expects the Input to be Seq[ColumnRef]. So I typecast Seq[String] to Seq[ColumnRef]. It then failed with below exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.datastax.spark.connector.ColumnRef